# Putting limits on estimated coefficient values

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

I recently came across an example of using eviews to put non-linear/convex limits
on estimated coeficients on OLS.

I could track down a link to a forum describing how this is done ([here](http://forums.eviews.com/viewtopic.php?p=103#p103))...

But I don't actually know anything more about how these models are estimated in practice. Has anyone a link to a paper/book/source code/explanation on how this is  *implemented* in practice?

## Question update:

Using cardinal's answer to my orginal question i have been able to solve this problem using $\verb+optim()+$ --just replacing $\beta$ by $1-\exp(\beta)$ in the minus log likelihood equation and minimizing itteratively. Now i would like to solve it using $\verb+nls()+$. So for example, in the following case:

```
library(MASS)
#coefficients bounded by 1
n<-100
p<-2
x<-mvrnorm(n,rep(0,p),diag(p))
t1<-4
t2<-1.5
t3<--2
y<-cbind(1,x)%*%c(t1,t2,t3)
y<-y+rnorm(n,0,2)
```

i get $1-\exp(\hat{t}_2)=1$ and $1-\exp(\hat{t}_3)=-2$. So my question now is can this be done with $\verb+nls()+$?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking about how to do this in the software you link to (which I'm not familiar with) or if you want to know the background on how it might be implemented under the hood. It seems like the latter, but I wanted to check.

Comment: @cardinal: the latter!

Comment: Well, the log likelihood of many models are concave (in particular, linear and certain formulations of generalized linear models). So maximizing them over a convex set becomes a convex program for which many fairly general computing packages exist. Does that help? Should I elaborate more in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply changing OLS problem to NLS one. Let us say we have the model

$$y_i=\alpha_0+\alpha_1x_i+\varepsilon_i$$

Say we want to make $\alpha_1$ positive, then rewrite this equation as

$$y_i=\alpha_0+\exp(\beta_1)x_i+\varepsilon_i$$

Algebraically this is the same, we only have different reparametrisation. Instead of $(\alpha_0,\alpha_1)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_+$ we have now $(\alpha_0,\beta_1)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and we can estimate the second equation using non-linear least squares.

Here is how we can achieve this in R:

```
> x<-rnorm(100)
> y<-1+2*x+rnorm(100)/5
> lm(y~x)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     0.9794       1.9895  

> nls(y~a+exp(b)*x,start=list(a=0.9,b=log(2)-0.3))
Nonlinear regression model
  model:  y ~ a + exp(b) * x 
   data:  parent.frame() 
     a      b 
0.9794 0.6879 
 residual sum-of-squares: 3.694

Number of iterations to convergence: 3 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.09e-06 
> exp(0.6879)
[1] 1.989533
```

Of course since you convert OLS problem to NLS you need to supply starting values. In Eviews it is done automatically. Note however that Eviews may happily blurt out the answer even if it is not correct, i.e. convergence was not achieved. This at least was my personal experience in working with it.

**Update** The last example in the link is not correct. Suppose you have the constraints $\alpha_0+\alpha_1=1$ and $\alpha_0,\alpha_1>0$, then the problem actually has only one parameter:

$$y=\alpha+(1-\alpha)x+\varepsilon$$

Then you can use reparametrisation:

$$\alpha=\frac{\beta}{1+\exp(\beta)}$$

Here is the implementation in R:

```
> y<-0.3+0.7*x+rnorm(100)/5
> lm(y~x)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     0.3175       0.7402  

> nls(y~exp(a)/(exp(a)+1)+(1/(exp(a)+1))*x,start=list(a=-0.5))
Nonlinear regression model
  model:  y ~ exp(a)/(exp(a) + 1) + (1/(exp(a) + 1)) * x 
   data:  parent.frame() 
      a 
-0.8876 
 residual sum-of-squares: 4.073

Number of iterations to convergence: 3 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 4.069e-09 
> exp(-0.8876)
[1] 0.4116425
```

Note however the discrepancy between the generated value and the resulting coefficient. Also if you will try to use the reparametrisation suggested in the link:

$$\alpha_0=\frac{\exp(\beta_0)}{\exp(\beta_0)+\exp(\beta_1)}$$
$$\alpha_1=\frac{\exp(\beta_1)}{\exp(\beta_0)+\exp(\beta_1)}$$

you will have an ill posed NLS problem and `nls` will complain about singular gradients.

Comment: While this is a good idea in a pinch, I would *hope* this is not how it's done in your favorite software for examples like this. In this case we just have a straightforward quadratic program.

Comment: thanks for the help mpiktas, but the function doesn't do what i want. In your example, the transformed coefficients b is larger than 1 (it should be 1 exactly, since this is the closest, among all *allowed* value, to the OLS solution).

Comment: @user603: I don't understand your most recent comment. The example shown indicates the coefficient estimates are identical using both methods of estimation. That's *exactly* what you want in this instance. Can you clarify?

Comment: no: i want 1-exp(\hat{b})<=1 (and since in this case the real b is >1, then  1-exp(\hat{b}) should be equal to 1. Think of a soft version of the "L-BFGS-B" algorithm. For bounds on a single variable it should give the same result as "L-BFGS-B" bounds, but could be extended to a convex constraint involving several parameter (think of the 'all positive and summing to 1' constraint, the last one in the eviews examples). FWIW i've been able to bootstrap your comment to my question unto a function that does just that using optim(). Now i would want to be able to do it via nls().

Comment: @user603: The inequality you give is equivalent to $\exp(\hat{b}) \geq 0$ which is trivially(!) true.

Comment: @cardinal [?] of course so as to ensure that if b<1 1-\exp{\hat{b})\approx b (i.e. equal the unconstrained solution since as you put it then the constraint is trivially verified). Then, '[...]and since in this case the real b is >1, then 1-exp(\hat{b}) should be equal to 1[...]'

Comment: @user603, I gave an easy example, for illustration. This example does not coincide with either of the examples given in the link. Could you update the question with precise problem you want to solve?

Comment: @user603: Your question asks something very general, yet in the comments you've appeared to have something much more specific in mind. Perhaps this is why I'm having difficulty following your train of thought. I agree with mpiktas that an edit to your question would be helpful, especially if you have a particular example in mind.

Comment: @cardinal/mpiktas: does the edit helps (i think its a particular example) --is it enough?

Comment: @user603, I've updated my answer, but to your previous question, since I've composed the update with interruptions. The new update helps a bit, but could you write the exact model you are trying to fit together with restrictions? LateX instead of code would be very helpful.

Comment: @mpiktas: indeed, in light of cardinal's comment (and the fact that i could use it to get a working implementation using optim()) my question has changed quiet a bit from 'how to implement this?' to 'how to express this optim() code in nls() terms?'. What i will do is to accept your answer (for the effort and to close this) and re-ask the question.